# py.test reporting on skipped tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am using `py.test -rfs` to get additional reports on failed and skipped tests.

There are two ways by which a test gets skipped:

1. by calling `pytest.skip(msg)` from inside of a test case
2. by decorating a test case: `@pytest.mark.skipif(condition, msg)`

In the final report, if I use `pytest.skip()` I get lines int the following form:

```
path/testmodule:linenumber: message`
```

The name of the test case (which is not there) would be great but this way it's certainly good enough.

But when I use `pytest.mark.skipif()`, what I get is this:

```
SKIP [1] /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/skipping.py:132: message
```

Not even the test module name. The path to always the same line from inside py.test ifself is not really helpful.

I certainly could put the name of the test case into the message but if there is a more elegant way of getting the report better, it would be great. Does anyone know of that?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `-rfs`, you should use `-v`:

```
$ py.test -v t.py 
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.8 -- py-1.4.23 -- pytest-2.6.0 -- /usr/bin/python
collected 2 items 

t.py@3::test_1 SKIPPED
t.py@7::test_2 SKIPPED

========================== 2 skipped in 0.01 seconds ==========================
```

---

The above output comes from the following file:

```
import pytest

def test_1():
    pytest.skip('msg')


@pytest.mark.skipif(True, reason='msg')
def test_2():
    pass
```